# laravel 5 loading addresses in google map api

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, laravel

I am new to json and laravel and I would like to put my question forward.

I have a database table called `dealer_address` which has **id, address, state, pin, city.**

My javascript to load the map with some addresses are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#test1').gmap3({
            map:{
                options:{
                    center:[46.578498,2.457275],
                    zoom: 5
                }
            },
            marker:{
                values:[
                    {latLng:[48.8620722, 2.352047], data:"Paris !"},
                    {address:
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/maps2/',
                            type: 'get',
                            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            success: function (results) {
                                console.log(results);
                            }
                        })}
                ],
                options:{
                    draggable: false
                },
                events:{
                    mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
                        var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
                        if (infowindow){
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            infowindow.setContent(context.data);
                        } else {
                            $(this).gmap3({
                                infowindow:{
                                    anchor:marker,
                                    options:{content: context.data}
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    mouseout: function(){
                        var infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
                        if (infowindow){
                            infowindow.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

However, I would like to display addresses on the map from the database result.

```
public function ShowData()
{
    $location = '700016';
    $results = DB::table('dealer_address')
        ->where('dealer_address.city', 'LIKE', '%'.$location.'%')
        ->orWhere('dealer_address.pincode', 'LIKE', '%'.$location.'%')
        ->orWhere('dealer_address.state', 'LIKE', '%'.$location.'%')
        ->get();

    dd($results);
    return View::make('/maps2')->with('data', json_encode($results));

}
```

My `dd($results)` is working fine. Where and what do I need to change in my javascript to pass this json ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify your return statement to this:

```
return json_encode($results->toArray());
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but I have already taken care of that. My question was, where do I change in JAVASCRIPT on the view blade to caputure the json and how. I am new to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2

```
return Response::json($results->toArray());
```

Laravel 5.1

```
return response()->json($results->toArray());
```

You could create

```
var options = [your data]
```

and after call `$('#test1').gmap3(options)`

When you have `options`
You can call ajax for json data and setit

```
options.marker.values.address[0] = response
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but I have already taken care of that. My question was, where do I change in JAVASCRIPT on the view blade to caputure the json and how. I am new to JSON